# Does exist any utility to know the size of a compiled function in an executable?

Tags: debugging, binary, executable, filesize, utility

I want a report showing me the size of diferent symbols(compiled) in the executable. Something like .map files in Delphi, but generic if possible. nm from binutils, shows start address(?), maybe could i use that information?

(I'm using object pascal + freepascal compiler)

Answer (score 0):

- FPC/LD can generate mapfiles too
- various ways to analyze .o files. (nm, objdump and parse the address increments between sections)
- maybe the information is stored in the .ppu, have a look in the ppu unit (compiler dir) which contains .ppu loaders